# How to update values using case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, case-when

I have created update statement like below

```
    UPDATE  dbo.S_Item
    SET     SalePrice3 = CASE WHEN Price <0 THEN '-1'
        when Price=1 then 11
        when Price=2 then 22
        when Price=3 then 33
        when Price=4 then 44
        when Price=5 then 55
        when Price=6 then 66
        when Price=7 then 77
        when Price=8 then 88
        when Price=9 then 99
        when Price=0 then 00     
     end
```

but i want update more values using above statement for example if want update price=123 it has to update 112233,if price=456 it has to update 445566,if price=725 it has to update 772255 how can achieve this help me

Comment: What is the exact problem? Strictly seen, adding 3 more more when statements would solve your problem, no?

Comment: If it is 3 statements i can add but if it is more for example price value any thing between 10 to 1000 should i write thousand statements?

Comment: Do you want separate mappings for all of the input values or ranges or...?

Answer (score 3):

```
Create Function ReplicateDigits (
@Number Int)
Returns BigInt
    Begin

    Declare @Step SmallInt = 1,
        @Result nVaRchar(100) = N''

    While (@Step <= Len(@Number))
        Begin 
        Select @Result = @Result + Replicate(SubString(Cast(@Number As Varchar), @Step, 1), 2)
        Select @Step = @Step + 1
        End

    Return Cast(@Result As BigInt)

    End
Go
```

Then:

```
  UPDATE    dbo.S_Item
        SET SalePrice3 = CASE
                           WHEN Price <0 THEN '-1'
                           Else dbo.ReplicateDigits(Price)
                         End
```

Let me know if it was useful.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick response now it is fine in my system i will check in server and inform you

Answer (score 1):

If the point is just in duplication of every digit, here's another implementation of the duplication method:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DuplicateDigits(@Input int)
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(20) = CAST(@Input AS varchar(20));
  DECLARE @Pos    int         = LEN(@Result);
  WHILE @Pos > 0
  BEGIN
    SET @Result = STUFF(@Result, @Pos, 0, SUBSTRING(@Result, @Pos, 1));
    SET @Pos -= 1;
  END;
  RETURN @Result;
END;
```

The method consists in iterating through the digits backwards, extracting each using `SUBSTRING` and duplicating it using `STUFF`.

And you would be using this function same as in [Meysam Tolouee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23751057/297408):

```
UPDATE  dbo.S_Item
SET     SalePrice3 = CASE
                         WHEN Price < 0 THEN '-1'
                         ELSE dbo.DuplicateDigits(SalePrice3)
                     END;
```

To explain a little why the function's returned type is `varchar`, it is because that guarantees that the function returns the result no matter what the input's [reasonable] length is. The maximum length of `20` has been chosen merely because the input is [assumed to be] `int` and positive `int` values consist of up to 10 digits.

However, whether `varchar(20)` converts to the type of `SalePrice3` is another matter, which should be considered separately.

Answer (score 0):

Youy Must Create a Procedure for Achiving the Desired Result Rather Than to Use a Single Query.

Comment: I am new to sql server can you help